# Creating Summary Report for Product Hierarchies in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Products` table that contains the following columns:

```
CategoryId, SubCategoryId, ProductId, 
Name (this can be either CategoryName, SubCategoryName, or ProductName)
```

For example, if I have a product called Dell Laptop in subcategory `Computers` in category `Electronics`, then I might have three rows:

```
CategoryID | SubCategoryId    | ProductID     | Name
-----------+------------------+---------------+-------------
1          | NULL             |    NULL       | Electronics
1          | 18               |    NULL       | Computers
1          | 18               |    123        | Dell Laptop
2          | NULL             |    NULL       | Sporting Goods
2          | 28               |    NULL       | Bicycles
```

And a `Sales` table that contains the following columns:

```
CategoryId, SubCategoryId, ProductId, SalesAmount
```

Some sales are at the category level, others at the subcategory level, and some at the product level.

So `Sales` might look like:

```
CategoryID | SubCategoryId | ProductID | SalesAmount
-----------+---------------+-----------+----------------
    1      | NULL          |  NULL     | 100.00
    2      | 28            |  NULL     |  50.00
    1      | NULL          |  NULL     | 125.00
    1      | 18            |  123      | 425.00
```

I'm trying to create a report that shows:

```
CategoryId, SubCategoryId, ProductId, Name, Total Sales without double or triple counting anything. For the above example, the intended result would be:

CategoryID | SubCategoryId     | ProductID     | Name        | TotalSales
-----------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------
1          |  NULL             |  NULL         | Electronics | $225
1          |  A                |  A123         | Dell Laptop | $425
2          |  D                |  NULL         | Bicycles    |  $50
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    p.CategoryId, p.SubCategoryId, p.ProductId, [Name], SUM(SalesAmount)
FROM 
    Products p 
LEFT JOIN 
    Sales s ON p.CategoryId = s.CategoryId
            AND p.SubCategoryId = s.SubCategoryId
            AND p.ProductId = s.ProductId
GROUP BY 
    p.CategoryId, p.SubCategoryId, p.ProductId, p.[Name];
```

My results:

```
1   NULL    NULL    Electronics NULL
1    18     NULL    Computers   NULL
1    18     123     Dell Laptop 425.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You need INNER join and handle the nulls in join condition:

```
SELECT 
    p.CategoryId, p.SubCategoryId, p.ProductId, [Name], SUM(SalesAmount)
FROM 
    Products p 
INNER JOIN 
    Sales s ON p.CategoryId = s.CategoryId
            AND ISNULL(p.SubCategoryId,0) = ISNULL(s.SubCategoryId,0)
            AND ISNULL(p.ProductId,0) = ISNULL(s.ProductId,0)
GROUP BY 
    p.CategoryId, p.SubCategoryId, p.ProductId, p.[Name];
```